# Python Socket UDP WinError 10040

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I'm trying to stream JSON data over UDP to another computer. For this i created this simple class. It does work but after a while i get the OS error:

> OSError: [WinError 10040] A message sent on a datagram socket was larger than the internal message buffer or some other network limit, or the buffer used to receive a datagram into was smaller than the datagram itself

My packet size are around 128 bytes but is send them +- 20 time a second. The bigger the packet the faster i get this error. The also happends when on the recieving side nothing is connected.

What am i doing wrong?

```
import socket
import json

class JSON_UDP:
    def __init__(self,send_ip='127.0.0.1', send_port=7002):
        self.send_ip = send_ip
        self.send_port = send_port      
        self.sender = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
 
    def send(self,input,send_ip='127.0.0.1', send_port=7002):
        self.send_ip = send_ip
        self.send_port = send_port
        self.input = input
        data = json.dumps(self.input)
        data = bytes(data,encoding="utf-8")
        print(len(data))

        self.sender.sendto(data, (self.send_ip, self.send_port))
```

Tried it set a buffer size but without succes

```
        self.buff_size = 1024
        self.sender.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_RCVBUF,self.buff_size)
        self.sender.bind(('0.0.0.0',0))
```

Comment: This error really happens on the sending side?

Comment: Yes this error comes from the python script i'm sending the data from. It also only sends data and does not need to listen to any data.

On the receiver side, i'm using TouchDesigner and eventually Unreal or Unity.

But is also happens with no listener on the other side.